# Gatsby TypeError: Cannot read property 'allWordpressAcfOptions' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I would like to be able to retrieve data from ACF option pages. I'm able to get my values here http://localhost:8000/___graphql but not in my project.

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const Users = ({ data }) => {

    return (
        <div id="Users">
            {
                data.allWordpressAcfOptions.edges.node.options.employees.map(employees => (
                     console.log(employees)
                ))
            }

        </div>
    )
}


export default Users;

export const query = graphql`
{
  allWordpressAcfOptions {
    edges {
      node {
        options {
          employees {
            wordpress_id
            first_name
            last_name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

So after I ran the Query it looks something like this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "__typename": "Query",
    "allWordpressAcfOptions": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "options": {
              "employees": [
                {
                  "wordpress_id": "1",
                  "first_name": "bob ",
                  "last_name": "joe",
                  "email": "emal@gmail.com",
                  "username": "user1",
                  "password": "password",
                  "status": "active"
                },
                {
                  "wordpress_id": "2",
                  "first_name": "sam",
                  "last_name": "more",
                  "email": "email@yahoo.com",
                  "username": "user2",
                  "password": "password",
                  "status": "active"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is way it suppose to look but, for some reason its throwing that error. In the Query I notice that it automatically imputed "__typename" at the top in "___graphql". Do i need to include this in my query inside my project.

Bellow is my gatsby-config.js file. I followed the examples and this is what I end up with. For some reason it is not recognizing "allWordpressAcfOptions".

```
module.exports = {

  siteMetadata:{
    title: "Gatsby Website",
    description: "",
    keywords: "ben, joe",
    image: "/static/images/1.jpg",
    url: 'https://website.com'
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Name`,
        short_name: `Name`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#f7f0eb`,
        theme_color: `#a2466c`,
        display: `standalone`,
      },
    },
    {resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`},
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
      options: {
        /*
         * The base URL of the WordPress site without the trailingslash and the protocol. This is required.
         * Example : 'gatsbyjsexamplewordpress.wordpress.com' or 'www.example-site.com'
         */
        baseUrl: "website.com",

        // The protocol. This can be http or https.
        protocol: "https",

        // Indicates whether the site is hosted on wordpress.com.
        // If false, then the assumption is made that the site is self hosted.
        // If true, then the plugin will source its content on wordpress.com using the JSON REST API V2.
        // If your site is hosted on wordpress.org, then set this to false.
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: true,
        acfOptionPageIds: [],
        cookies: {},
        verboseOutput: false,
        perPage: 100,
        concurrentRequests: 10,
        includedRoutes: [
          "**/categories",
          "**/posts",
          "**/pages",
          "**/media",
          "**/tags",
          "**/taxonomies",
          "**/users",
        ],
        keepMediaSizes: false,
        normalizer: function({ entities }) {
          return entities
        },
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

So, if I pass the value as props from another page via the component then it works.

```
<Users data={data.allWordpressAcfOptions}></Users>
```

When I try to do it as a component like so

```
const Users = ({data}) => {
  console.log(data);
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
}
```

The value is empty console.log(data); undefined

Comment: What does the data look like after the query?

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting `data.allWordpressAcfOptions.edges` to be an array right? 
So you need to map over that first. Then again map over each `WordpressAcfOption`'s employees array.

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const Users = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        data.allWordpressAcfOptions.edges.map(edge => {
          return (
            <div>
              edge.node.options.employees.map(employee => {
                return (
                  <div>{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name}</div>
                )
              })
            <div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}


export default Users

export const query = graphql`
{
  allWordpressAcfOptions {
    edges {
      node {
        options {
          employees {
            wordpress_id
            first_name
            last_name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

## Edit:

If `Users` is not a page component, this query will not ever be run by gatsby. You should convert this component to use a [static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/). Something like this should work: (untested)

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

const Users = () => {
        const { allWordpressAcfOptions } = useStaticQuery(
        graphql`query {
          allWordpressAcfOptions {
            edges {
              node {
                options {
                  employees {
                    wordpress_id
                    first_name
                    last_name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }`
      )

  return (
    <div>
      {
        allWordpressAcfOptions.edges.map(edge => {
          return (
            <div>
              edge.node.options.employees.map(employee => {
                return (
                  <div>{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name}</div>
                )
              })
            <div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}


export default Users

export const query = graphql`
{
  allWordpressAcfOptions {
    edges {
      node {
        options {
          employees {
            wordpress_id
            first_name
            last_name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'allWordpressAcfOptions' of undefined

Comment: Is this a page component?

Comment: Its a component.

Comment: If it's not a page component, then your graphql query is not being run.